# Angular Enum in dropdown

Tags: html, typescript, angular8

Всем привет! Народ помогите что я делаю не так, не могу вставить Enum в dropdown
Создал отельный файл :

```
export enum Level
{
    First = 1,
    Second
}
```

Затем у себя в компоненте

```
export class MyComponent extends BaseComponent {
  constructor() {

  }
  keys = Object.keys;
  levels = Level;
  isNumber(val) { return typeof val === 'number'; }
}
```

И после этого уже в html:

```
 <div class="form-group row">
              <label for="Level" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">{{'Level' | translate }}</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="model.level" name="Level">
                  <ng-container *ngFor="let level of keys(levels)">
                    <option *ngIf="!isNumber(level)" [ngValue]="Level[level]">{{level}}</option>
                  </ng-container>
                </select>
              </div>
```

Но у меня в выпадающем списке все равно присутствуют значения 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как мне сделать так чтоб в выпадающем списке были только:

First
Second

Answer (score 0):

В общем после разных попыток, пришел к выводу что проще в компоненте фильтровать свой Enum
 и сделал следующее:

```
  public LevelList = Object.keys(Level)
  .filter(x => typeof this.levels[x] === 'number');
```

и в html сменил :

```
<div class="form-group row">
              <label for="Level" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">{{'App.Level' | translate }}</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="model.Level" name="Level">
                  <ng-container *ngFor="let level of LevelList">
                    <option  [ngValue]="Level[level]">{{level}}</option>
                  </ng-container>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
```